# Adjust NSOutlineView or NSTableView cell height to the custom view within

Tags: swift, autolayout, swiftui, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` view that uses a custom SwiftUI view as its cells:

```swift
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
    guard tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "the correct id" else { return }
    guard let myItem = item as? MyType else { return }
    return NSHostingView(rootView: MySwiftUIView(someProperty: myItem))
}
```

The custom view's height can change, so I want to find a way to dynamically adjust the `NSOutlineView` cells' height to the custom views hosted within.  So far, I have only found this function in `NSOutlineViewDelegate` that allows me to set the height of a row:

```swift
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, heightOfRowByItem item: Any) -> CGFloat
```

However, I'm only able to set a row's height based on the `item`, not the custom view.

Is there anyway for me to access each cell/row directly, and set its height equal to the that of the custom view?

Comment: You already know based off the code you wrote what View is being made for the item (MySwiftUIView). You should be able to just return the default height of that view.

Comment: @RichardSmall Do you mean recreating the `MySwiftUIView` instance for `item`, and then reading its height?

Comment: If your view is a constant height that would work, or store the view you created in the item itself as well. Possibly using a weak reference to avoid a retain cycle.